# How ART Virtual Machine is going to affect existing applications?

Tags: android, virtual-machine, dalvik

This is not a programming issue or problem so far (at least not for me currently), but I thought that might be useful to discuss this which could help us to prevent further problems we might have.

Since I changed the Virtual Machine in Nexus 5, from Dalvik to ART, I started having some crashes with the Apps I currently have in my device. I first realised it with WhatsApp application. It stopped working.

I started to test all of my applications for compatibility with ART. I didn't have any crashes so far but I'm wondering that If we need to do something in order to make our apps more compatible with ART and have more efficiency ? How is it going to affect our existing applications ?

Comment: When you give a Down Vote, you need to explain the reason !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robert Love provided [some details](http://www.quora.com/Android-OS/Why-is-ART-better-than-Dalvik/answer/Robert-Love-1?srid=u76C&share=1) over on a Quora answer.

Based on what I have seen, my guess is that the leading cause of ART incompatibilities will be on-the-fly DEX generation, if ART does not support that. With ART switching to an ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation model, instead of JIT, it's possible that ART will not support apps that generate DEX instructions. It's also possible that this is a limitation of the work-in-progress ART, one that will be rectified at in a later update.

It is conceivable that the cited "improved garbage collection" could introduce incompatibilities, but that would surprise me. Somewhat more likely would be that a change in the GC behavior might expose existing application logic flaws that were masked by previous GC schemes.

And, of course, there may be other ART-specific issues that will crop up over time.

All that being said, bear in mind that ART is a work in progress. My guess is that Google released it mostly to provide an ART-powered runtime environment specifically for WhatsApp and similar larger partners. If you try running your app, and your app breaks on ART, it is probably worth some amount of investigation. However, if your app is fine on ART, it is likely to remain fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to do in terms of making your app compatible for now, ART is a work in development and as such will have problems with some apps, when the time comes that ART becomes standardised it will simply 'work', any contradiction to that fact, Google will release documentation on fixing accordingly.